How to write xUnit test for Validate of IValidatableObject?
I have IValidatableObject with Validate method. How to write unit test for this object and this method? (I use xUnit). How to mock context? Code of the object below.
Note: that object have an enum field.
public class Settings: IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; } //enum

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Category), Category))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Invalid Category", new[] { nameof(Category) });
        }
    }
}


In your class there only Validate method that has logic, that is useful to be tested. Here's example how it could be set up:
[Theory]
[InlineData(10_000)]
[InlineData(10_000_000)]
public void WhenInvalidCategory_ReturnsError(int category)
{
    // Arrange
    var settings = new Settings();
    settings.Category = (Category)category;

    // Act
    var validationResults = settings.Validate(
        new ValidationContext(settings));

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotEmpty(validationResults);
}

You only need to adjust creation of ValidationContext accordingly to linked post

Yes, I created context:
var validationContext = new ValidationContext(settings);
